# Error of GetCollection() function of IBM Watson in .net standard

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-watson, watson-discovery

Watson's GetCollection() gives an error.

Gives api failed error "ServiceResponseException: The API query failed with status code InternalServerError: Internal Server Error | x-global-transaction-id: ffea405d5c3bf8471c1ddde9 | X-DP-Watson-Tran-ID: gateway02-471719401"

https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/dotnet-standard-sdk/blob/development/examples/IBM.WatsonDeveloperCloud.Discovery.v1.Example/DiscoveryServiceExample.cs

The example from watson's github.

**class.cs**

```
using System;
using IBM.WatsonDeveloperCloud.Discovery.v1;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace automation
{
    public class watsonApiCalling
    {
        public DiscoveryService _discovery;
        public string _existingEnvironmentId = <your environment id>;
        public string _createdCollectionId = <your collection id>;
        public void activitateDiscovery(string url, string username, string password)
        {
            Console.Write("\n~ STARTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT");
            _discovery = new DiscoveryService(username, password, "2018-12-1");
            _discovery.SetEndpoint(url);
            var result = _discovery.GetCollection(_existingEnvironmentId, _createdCollectionId);

            Console.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Formatting.Indented));
        }

    }
}`
```

**ConsoleApp.cs**

```
using System;
using automation;

namespace ConsoleAppUI
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            watsonApiCalling watson = new watsonApiCalling();
            watson.activitateDiscovery("https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api", username, password);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

    }
}
```

Other function of API calling via watson works, only GetCollection() didn't.

Comment: It appear if i use my _existingEnvironmentId, _createdCollectionId it didn't work, but if i use "system" , "news-en" provided by watson it works...

Comment: oh but if i want a new collection?